# Passing values to OverlayScene from MainScene-Scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit

How do you pass a value from Main 3d SceneKit to the Overlay SpriteKit scene? 
Ive tried going through the ViewController but when setting the value in Overlay i get:

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is my current code:

MainScene:

```
//User Scored     
ViewController().doScore()
```

ViewController:

```
func doScore(){
    self.OverlayScene.score += 1
}
```

OverlayScene:

```
var score = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.scoreNode.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `spriteScene` ?

Comment: could you be more specific? There is an `overlaySKScene` on `SCNView`, but this appears to be a custom property.

Comment: score is just a variable in my overlaySKScene, which I'm trying to increment from the MainScene

Comment: `self.spriteScene.score` cannot compile (even assuming you meant `overlaySKScene` instead of `spriteScene`) because the view controller doesn't have a `overlaySKScene` property. The view does.